# How can I access MTP devices through the command line on Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, mtp

The file browser in Chrome OS can access MTP devices just fine, but it is not capable of doing cut-and-paste with files. How can I access MTP devices through the command line on a Chromebook? My Chromebook is already in developer mode and since the file browser can access MTP devices that means that there must be some way to create an accessible mount point of an MTP device using the command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

/media/fuse/fusebox/mtp.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).